# Why does my GitHub website homepage not load the background video and images on initial entry?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have deployed my first react website to GitHub and everything works except for the background video and card images loading on the initial entry into the page. If you visit another page and return to the homepage, everything loads in. It is only a problem on the initial entry.

[Imgur](https://imgur.com/8EIQzFA)

Here is the link to my page for reference: https://markel-bradford.github.io/react-portfolio/

Here is my repo: https://github.com/Markel-Bradford/react-portfolio

I have tried redeploying the building and have made sure that all of my routes are linked to the repository. I have also attempted using a more compressed video in .webm format to see if it was a load time issue due to a 64mb video files and got the same result. Is there any way to fix this show that it loads on initial entry?

Comment: If you add some code or at least a link to your repo someone can probably help you.

Comment: Take a look at your browsers developers tools. Especially the network tab. You are probably loading resources using a relative path instead of absolute path.  Your mp4 file is loaded from `/react-portfolio/react-portfolio` which indicates relative paths in your code

Comment: Sorry. Forgot the repo. I have added it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MP4 file and images were receiving the 404 error because they were written:

> /react-portfolio/react-**portfolio//video/video_2160.mp4**

Instead of:

> /react-portfolio/react-**portfolio/video/video_2160.mp4**

With the corrected path, the landing page now loads correctly.